# Change unity physics engine speed

Tags: unity, physics, unityscript

Is there a simple way to change the **speed*** of unity's physics engine like in the game [SuperHot](http://www.superhotgame.com)?

Any script language is ok but javascript is preferred.

*I am not sure if **speed** is the correct term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Time.TimeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) for slow motion effect.